# Why my cancan didn't work properly?

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, cancan

my envirenment:`ruby:2.0.0p0, rails:3.2.13, cancan: 1.6.10, devise: 2.2.4`
Hi, when i following the cancan's wiki [Separate-Role-Model](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Separate-Role-Model), and it seems didn't work for me?
when i [Debugging-Abilities](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Debugging-Abilities), i find the following:

```
2.0.0-p0 :002 > q = Question.first
  Question Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "questions".* FROM "questions" LIMIT 1
 => #<Question id: 1, title: "问题", created_at: "2013-05-14 11:14:31", updated_at: "2013-05-14 11:14:31", content: "答案", user_id: nil>
```

The `user_id` is `nil`.
I have already add the `user_id and role_id` to assignment table, `question_id` to user table, `user_id` to question table.
`role.rb`

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base                                                                                                                              
  attr_accessible :name                                                                                                                                      
#  has_and_belongs_to_many :users                                                                                                                            
  has_many :assignments                                                                                                                                      
  has_many :users, :through => :assignments                                                                                                                  
end
```

assgnment.rb

```
class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base                                                                                                                        
  # attr_accessible :title, :body                                                                                                                            
  belongs_to :user                                                                                                                                           
  belongs_to :role                                                                                                                                           
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base                                                                                                                              
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:                                                                                                    
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,                                                                                                                    
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable                                                                                                                
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,                                                                                                           
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable                                                                                               

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model                                                                                                
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :username, :profile                                                               
  # attr_accessible :title, :body                                                                                                                            

  has_many :assignments                                                                                                                                      
  has_many :roles, :through => :assignments                                                                                                                  
  has_many :questions                                                                                                                                        

  def has_role?(role_sym)                                                                                                                                    
    roles.any? { |r| r.name.underscore.to_sym == role_sym }                                                                                                  
  end                                                                                                                                                        
end
```

ability.rb

```
class Ability                                                                                                                                                
  include CanCan::Ability                                                                                                                                    

  def initialize(user)                                                                                                                                       
      if user.blank?                                                                                                                                         
      cannot :manage, :all                                                                                                                                   
      can :read, Question                                                                                                                                    
    elsif user.has_role?(:admin)                                                                                                                             
      can :manage, :all                                                                                                                                      
    else                                                                                                                                                     
      can :create, Question                                                                                                                                  
      can :update, Question, :active => true, :user_id => user.id                                                                                            
      can :destroy, Question, :active => true, :user_id => user.id                                                                                           
    end                                                                                                                                                      
  end                                                                                                                                                        
end
```

And the view:

```
<% if can? :update, @question %>                                                                                                                     
   <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_question_path(question), :method => :get, :class => "btn btn-mini btn-warning" %>                                         
<% end %>
```

Then when i create a question but it doesn't come with an `edit` button. What's wrong with me? if you need more information, please tell me.

Comment: At your Ability class, try to just put can :manage, :all without any if statement or checking .. to see if the problem in your if statements or not ..

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your Ability class like this

```
class Ability                                                                                                                                                
  include CanCan::Ability                                                                                                                                    

  def initialize(user)                                                                                                                                       
      can :manage, :all                                                                                                                                      
  end                                                                                                                                                        
end
```

just to see if the problem still there or not? then your can gradually add your authorize logic to see where it breaks ..